# Is there a way to perform Dynamo Db Transaction on more than 25 items?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

As per AWD documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html -

```
These actions can target up to 25 distinct items in one or more   
DynamoDB tables within the same AWS account and in the same Region.   
The aggregate size of the items in the transaction cannot exceed 4 MB.  
The actions are completed atomically so that either all of them succeed or none of them succeeds.
```

What is the best way if we want to perform transaction for items more than 25 in number ?

Comment: Re-think your database design or look for a mutex/locking client library that you can use to build an uber-transaction that surrounds your multiple 25-item native transactions?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, as of Sep 6, 2022**

[Amazon DynamoDB now supports up to 100 actions per transaction](https://aws.amazon.com/de/about-aws/whats-new/2022/09/amazon-dynamodb-supports-100-actions-per-transaction/)